# How to extract the output from stdout.lines in ansible

Tags: ansible, mikrotik, ansible-template

```
---
- name: Mikrotik info
  hosts: mikrotik
  connection: network_cli
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: show info
    routeros_command:
     commands: /system routerboard print
    register: rb_info

  - name: Debug info
    debug:
      msg: "{{ rb_info.stdout_lines }}"
```

Output:

```
 routerboard: yes
             model: 751G-2HnD
     serial-number: 3A6502B2A2E7
     firmware-type: ar7240
  factory-firmware: 3.0
  current-firmware: 6.42.3
  upgrade-firmware: 6.43.4
```

I need to filter it for "upgrade-firmware" string and get output like this:

```
upgrade-firmware: 6.43.4
```

I should use regex_replace? Or I can use grep or something like that?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(update)

Use *from_yaml* and *combine* a dictionary. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        minfo: "{{ minfo|default({})|combine(item|from_yaml) }}"
      loop: "{{ rb_info.stdout_lines }}"
    - debug:
        var: minfo['upgrade-firmware']
```

give

```yaml
  minfo['upgrade-firmware']: 6.43.4
```

---

(for the record)

1. Robust solution is to write the data to *template* and *include_vars*. The tasks below

```yaml
    - tempfile:
      register: tempfile
    - template:
        src: minfo.j2
        dest: "{{ tempfile.path }}"
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ tempfile.path }}"
        name: minfo
    - debug:
        var: minfo
```

with the template

```yaml
    shell> cat minfo.j2 
    {% for item in rb_info.stdout_lines %}
    {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
```

should give

```yaml
    "minfo": {
        "current-firmware": "6.42.3", 
        "factory-firmware": 3.0, 
        "firmware-type": "ar7240", 
        "model": "751G-2HnD", 
        "routerboard": true, 
        "serial-number": "3A6502B2A2E7", 
        "upgrade-firmware": "6.43.4"
    }
```

2. The tasks below creates variable *upgrade_firmware*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        upgrade_firmware: "{{ item.split(':').1|trim }}"
      loop: "{{ rb_info.stdout_lines|map('quote')|map('trim')|list }}"
      when: item is search('^upgrade-firmware')
    - debug:
        var: upgrade_firmware
```

3. It is possible to put all the parameters into the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        minfo: "{{ minfo|default({})|
                   combine({item.split(':').0: item.split(':').1|trim}) }}"
      loop: "{{ rb_info.stdout_lines|map('quote')|map('trim')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: minfo['upgrade-firmware']
```

Comment: Thanks!
But I've hot an error
`fatal: [10.1.1.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item is search('^upgrade-firmware')' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if item is search('^upgrade-firmware') %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/user/scripts/mikrotik.update/mikrotik-info.yml': line 12, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    register: rb_info\n  - set_fact:\n    ^ here\n"}`

Comment: Try  `item|quote is search('^upgrade-firmware')`. You'll have to test it. Sorry, I don't have the rb_info.

Comment: Yeah, i changed. And now output is: 
`TASK [set_fact] * skipping: [10.1.1.1] => (item=[u'routerboard: yes', u' model: 750', u' serial-number: 3B0202EEEFB4', u' firmware-type: ar7240', u' factory-firmware: 2.38', u' current-firmware: 3.19', u' upgrade-firmware: 6.43.4']) TASK [debug] ***********************************************ok: [10.1.1.1] => { "upgrade_firmware": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" }`
 I should defined variable in another playse? And Is it possible to hide the "TASK [set_fact] part?

Comment: The problem is the extra space at the beginning of the string. Add filter `map('trim')`. See the updated answer.